# How to add DEP exclusion through registry in Win Server 2003 x64

Tags: windows, compatibility, dep

Is there a way to add an exclusion in DEP in Windows 2003 using registry?

I tried adding through registry:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlag\Layers
DisableNXShowUI=<path>
```

After adding manually through registry, I can see the entry coming in DEP tab but the program crashes when I launch.

Comment: Why not use `VirtualProtect()` appropriately?

Comment: This is used during the installation of an application.

Comment: You have a typo: `AppCompatFlagS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl, NoExecuteAddFileOptOutList "FullPathToExecutable
```

Use the above command. It worked for a 32-bit executable in Windows Server 2003 64-bit environment.